# ms outlook inbox autoforward

Tags: email, outlook, ms-office, forwarding

From time to time I need to forward some of my inbox messages (some of the clients) to myself because I need the text of the message (for parsing) including subject, from fields.
Is there an option or a better way to select and automatically forward these messages in outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very comprehensive explanation with images is available [here](http://www.technipages.com/automatically-forward-email-in-outlook-2010-2007.html).

Add your clients in step 3 where you define the conditions. In the image, first option (with check box) will allow you to do that.